# Who coined the term "Cloud Cuckoo Land"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

*Cloud Cuckoo Land* in English is a term often used to describe an unrealistically utopian idea of how things are.

> You're living in Cloud Cuckoo Land.

However how did the term get started to be used? Who coined it or made it popular?

Comment: Don't know the first appearance, but it was featured in Swift's "Gulliver's Travels" as a thinly-veiled satire of the leading scientists of the day, The Royal Academy of Sciences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It originally came from an Ancient Greek satirical play by Aristophanes ([The Birds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birds_%28play%29) 414BC), in which the original Greek *Νεφελοκοκκυγία* was often translated as **Cloud cuckoo town** until the early 1900s. In the play it *is* a town (or *city*, more exactly - but it's Ancient Greece, so we're not talking London or New York here).

The 20s and 30s saw a [sudden upsurge](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Cloud%20Cuckoo%20Land,Cloud%20Cuckoo%20Town&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in the "Cloud Cuckoo **Land**" form. I think initially this was particularly in political invective (newspaper, radio, later tv). Possibly because the supposedly 'erudite' association with classical learning prevented it being deemed ['unparliamentary language'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unparliamentary_language) in Britain (or the equivalent in the US). Later usages diverge somewhat from the exact nature of the satirical original; they often just mean "unrealistic to the point of insanity", with no recognition of the aspirations for "social justice" those early birds forlornly hoped to achieve.

I can't resist quoting from the Wikipedia link above. Remember it's a play competing with others for accolades at its inaugural performance in the 414BC festival (open air, doubtless). After some rather surreal law-making, the birds deliver a [parabasis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parabasis) (aside from playwright to audience), which *"ends by advising the festival judges to award them first place or risk getting crapped on"*.

I like that bit! Aristophanes's play  actually lost out to Ameipsias's *Comastae* at that City Dyonisia; I'd like to hope some real birds did the dirty deed!

Comment: Did anyone in particular make it more popular?  It's a curious phrase to just come out of the ether.

Comment: @Jez, the ["Cloud cuckoo land" wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_cuckoo_land) lists a number of famous quotes using the phrase.  In more recent history, the list includes such names as Adolf Hitler, Schopenhauer, Bernard Ingham and Ann Widdecombe.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: I stand by my belief that 'educated' politicians were a significant factor in bringing the phrase into common parlance.

Answer (score 6):

@FumbleFingers is mostly right.  It's from Aristophanes' *The Birds*, where they are building Νεφελοκοκκυγία (Nephelokokkygia), literally "cloud-cukoo-place".  Schopenhauer revived it as *Wolkenkuckucksheim*, lit. "cloud-cukoo-home" but the *-heim* suffix is common for German city names.

Comment: Interesting point that the current usage, of an unrealistic idea, drives classicists mad: Aristophanes' city is built in record time and defeats the immortal gods.

Answer (score 0):

I always remember it as a phrase S.J. Perlmann used to describe Hollywood, which he attributed to the condition depicted in cartoons, where some one hit over the head and dazed was surrounded by a cloud of cuckoos swirling around his head.

Comment: Can you add a link to a source for this?