# Idiomatic expression for being totally off in ones statement/belief

Tags: expressions

I can put that as *wading in the darkness*, *being totally lost* or *taking a shot and missing big*. However, I'm looking for a **far more** metaphorical expression.

The subject of the epithet should be assumed to have stated an opinion or attempted an action of a very well defined aim. For instance:

> - "You can say *your home* or *you're home* - it doesn't matter which because we get your point."

or

> A shooter trying to erase all the data in a computer by shooting the screen.

In the local language, we say *they're out bicycling* and it means just what the above expression do **but** unless the interlocutor can infer the meaning from the context (or knows it from elsewhere), they'd have little chance of getting it right and any guess in that regard would be, well... *being out bicycling*... (tiny whoohoo-wave for the circular reference).

Comment: In *my* vernacular, such people are [away with the fairies](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/away-with-the-fairies)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Care to **reply** instead of **commenting**? It allows to comment in the right place, follow-ups etc.

Comment: If I had cared to post an *answer* rather than a *comment*, I would have done so. You're welcome to post a comment yourself explaining why *away with the fairies* either *is* or *isn't* the kind of term you're looking for, and you or anyone else is welcome to Copy&Paste it into an actual answer. Personally, I'd say there's a fair "metaphorical distance" between, say, *fumbling in the dark/clutching at straws* and *missing big/being way off-beam*. But do you actually care which end of that spectrum people pick up on?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, perhaps I used the expression incorrectly. I didn't really inquired whether you cared for that (since, as you perfectly correctly pointed out, it was evident that you didn't). It was meant as a polite and friendly request for you to reconsider. Apparently it suits you better to use comments, so I'll respect that. However, the way SE works, as far I understand, it's less appropriate that way. As for your question - I found your suggestion perfectly well-suited. In fact, it could be spot-on if you cared to post it as a reply. I'll take it into consideration anyway, of course.

Comment: np. I would just say that I think describing someone as *away with the fairies* occurs more often in contexts where it means *(permanently) mentally unhinged*, as opposed to your specific context (where it would mean something more akin to *recklessly/ignorantly **allowing your imagination to run away with you***). But per the implication of my last comment, I think you should focus the Q more sharply to clarify whether you're interested in "random wading around in intellectual space" and "committed direction, but hopelessly wrong".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Done.

Comment: Not wishing to be awkward, I don't see what the first example is getting at. I could point out out that you *can't* actually say "your" ***or*** "you're", because in speech they're unavoidably identical, but is that what you're getting at? That's to say - is the point of the example to show someone saying something "totally and demonstrably incorrect"? The second example seems to be in that general area.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Precisely. You suggested that I elaborate the question and I added *statement or action*, hence an example for each - both being **very** wrong, way off and - apparently - out in left field.

Comment: I think you guys are *out to lunch*!

Comment: @HotLicks Is that another suggestion for an idiom as requested or is my Vikingish simpleness stopping me from seeing a sophisticated point?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - You're off your rocker!

Comment: According to William Safire, *He's Looney Tunes* is [a policeman's way of describing a subject as crazed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+looney-tunes+is+a%22). But I'd say Safire is living in [Cloud Cuckoo Land](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33404/) if he thinks there's any reason to specifically associate that expression with what *policemen* say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider,

***out in left field*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+in+left+field%2Cout+of+left+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20in%20left%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20left%20field%3B%2Cc0)

> *Slang* Completely mistaken; wrong
>
> *Also*, **out of left field**. Eccentric, odd; also, mistaken. For example, *The composer's use of dissonance in this symphony is way out in left field*, or *His answer was out of left field*; he was totally wrong. This idiom refers to baseball's left field but the precise allusion is disputed

[Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/out--in--left--field)

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using [**off-base**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+base) which means:

> Wrong, **relying on a mistaken premise**, as in *His description of the
>   accounting system was totally off base*. This metaphoric term
>   originated in baseball, where a runner who steps off a base can be put
>   out. [c. 1940]

[The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms]

> Fig. unrealistic; inexact; **wrong** (Typically: be off-base; get off-base.): *I'm afraid
>   you're off base when you state that this problem will take care of
>   itself*. *You're way off base if you think I was to blame!*

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002]

You can add adverbs such as **totally** and **way** before it to intensify the idiom.

Comment: Good suggestion in general. I'll be using that expression as well. In this particular case, I specifically require a term that'll be incomprehensible to the interlocutor unless inferred from the context or know prior to the conversation. (Not because I want to confuse the audience but because I wish to exemplify the linguistic gotchas and wtfs.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose "He's gone off the deep end on this one." here.  "to go off the deep end" is synonymous with diverging from rationality while "on this one" limits the scope to a particular topic rather than making a general statement about the person's sanity.